# Oracle conditional Format of Date column

Tags: oracle

Is there any way to change the format of a date column output based on condition?

For example, i have a table TEST with 1 Column test_date (DATE type) with two values - 20.03.2013 and `NULL`.
I want to do a query like below:

```
Select

CASE when test_date is NULL then 'NA' ELSE test_date end from TEST;
```

But i get an error like `inconsistent char and date formats`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

But for your case you should format your date on your case statement, like this:

```
Select 
   CASE when test_date is NULL then 'NA' 
        ELSE to_char(test_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') end as date 
  from TEST
```

**Edit:**
As you said in your comments that you need the output format to be a date if it is not null You can't do this. As the output of a case statement should be the same type of the WHEN part.

Best option to you was pointed on the comments by @MaheswaranRavisankar. You have to use your specific date format for your excel sheet e.g if in your sheet the date format is DD/MM/YYYY you should put this format on the to_char function that way the excel will automatically convert this data to date if the column is formated as date.

Comment: Hi. Thank u. I have tried this. When u do this, the date value returned (20.03.2013) will also be of type char. But i want this to be of type date and 'NA' values alone be of type char since finally am going to copy all these returned values to excel for reporting.

Comment: When exported to excel, the datatype of the result is not going to be preserved, and it depends on the Excel cell property. So the String conversion should not impact you!

Comment: And you should put this requirements on your question.

Comment: When i copy to excel , these values of type char are stored in general format and therefore am not able to create a filter for dates (whereas the pure date columns are copied as date format in excel and so am able to create a filter for them). That's the reason i asked for date format to be returned by oracle

Comment: Hi Jorge, Am new to this stack overflow. Will corret myself from next time.cheers!!!

Comment: Hi Mahesh/ Jorge, any solution to this requirement??

Comment: @Vinod, I have did this so many times for my project. Try a format of date in TO_CHAR() that excel recognises, it should work. Other way your requirement is not possible, until you use specific PL/SQL or something.

Comment: Hi Mahesh...I got te thing by doing the formatting at excel side. But

Answer (score 0):

All `WHEN` parts of a `CASE` statement must return the same data type.

So you need to change the date to a string if you also want the value `NA` displayed:

```
case 
   when test_date is null then 'NA'
   else to_char(test_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me the query what you asked......

if u still getting the problem you can use the TO_CHAR() function

ex: CASE when test_date is NULL then 'NA' ELSE TO_CHAR(test_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') end from TEST;

Comment: Hi. Thank u. I have tried this. When u do this, the date value returned (20.03.2013) will also be of type char. But i want this to be of type date and 'NA' values alone be of type char since finally am going to copy all these returned values to excel for reporting.

Comment: @Vinod, an expression can only be of one type - it can be a string (e.g. `'NA'` or `'20/03/2013'`) or a date, but never both at the same time. `'NA'` cannot be converted to a date in any language I'm aware of.